# Why is there no Chromium for 64 bit Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: chromium, raspberrypi

I tried installing 64 bit Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on RPi3B+ but there was no package available for it in Software Boutique. Is there no 64 bit version of Chromium for 64 bit Ubuntu MATE 18.04?

Comment: Isn't all software for Pies 32bit?

Comment: The Software Boutique was never intended to have all software packages, it was created as a store for selected packages wanted by most users for that system, maybe they didn't consider browsers as key for pi's (*which is commonly seen as more of an appliance device?*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software boutique only contains a handfull of software chosen by the ubuntu mate developers because of how well those applications integrate in the mate desktop environment. If you want a graphical way to install all applications I suggest installing gnome software.

Answer (score -2):

You can install chromium in 64 bit Ubuntu MATE by using following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: The 64-bit version can be downloaded using this link.

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Google Chrome no longer supports 32-bit.

After downloading it, run the commands below to install it.

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: @ Mehta 1. 64-bit amd64 is not the same as [arm64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=arm64&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=chromium-browser) (Raspberry case). 2. Modern `apt`/`apt-get` allows to install deb-files directly with `sudo apt install ./file.deb`, so there is no need to fix dependencies with `sudo apt-get -f install` .